# Use of For loop in always block

Tags: verilog, fpga, vivado

I am writing a Verilog code for calculating the number of digits in a decimal number. In the code below I have initialised the value of c to be equal to a.
I was able to get the simulation results correctly but unable to syntesise and the error is due to 'c=a'. How can I get rid of the error ? Is there any other logic to calculate the number of digits ?

```
Error: [Synth 8-3380] loop condition does not converge after 2000 iterations
```

Code :-

```
module numdigits(a,b);
parameter n=100;
input [0:n-1] a;
output reg [0:n-1]b;   //THIS MODULE COUNTS THE NUMBER OF DIGITS IN DECIMAL FORM
reg [0:n-1] d,c;
always @(*)
begin 
    d=0;
    for(c=a;c>0;c=c/10)
    begin
    d=d+1;
    end
    b=d;
end 
endmodule
```

Comment: I am not having any issues with your module. Perhaps its a testbench or tool issue? See: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/24e3

Comment: @Hida I am using vivado software and why do we need a test bench to synthesize the code?  Its mainly for simuation, right?

Comment: I agree it didn't properly answer your question. However I would like to point out that you should always simulate your RTL to reduce time spent debugging on FPGA/synthesis feedback.

Comment: I'll give a hint: something like this will static unroll for you `d=0; b=0; for(c=1;c<{n{1'b1}};c=10*c) begin if(...) begin b = ... ; end d=d+1; end` fill in the `...`s.

Comment: @Greg `if(c>a) begin:abc b=d; disable abc end d=d=+1; end`. Is this right?

Comment: @VineethAnanthula , very close. Close enough that simulation can point out the error. I synthesized with Yosys on [edaplayground](https://edaplayground.com) (simulated there too) and found Yosys doesn't support `disable`. Other synthesizer may support `disable`, but it is not essential to get a synthesizable version of your desired functionality.

Comment: @Greg I have to instantiate this module in other top module. The thing is that I am using this in a multiplier algorithm project. So it is necessary to synthesize.

Comment: @Greg I think this `floor(log2(abs(a)))+1` works out, right ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a `for` loop to be synthesisable, it must be *static*: that is, the maximum number of iterations round the loop must be fixed. It might seem that there is a maximum number of iterations of your loop, given that `a` has a fixed number of bits, but remember that your synthesiser doesn't simulate your code, so it cannot tell that.

You need to refactor your code; you need to write it in such a way so that the maximum number of loop iterations is fixed. In other words, the number of iterations of the loop must be fixed, but you can jump out early if you wish (using the `disable` statement).

Comment: Is there any other logic for finding the number of digits in a number?

Comment: Well, your algorithm is fine, it's just not synthesisable the way you have written it. For starters, you need to go round a loop a fixed number of times: how about `n/3`? That's too many, but `n/4` is too few. Then to can keep dividing by ten and incrementing a counter, stopping when you reach zero. At that point you can jump out of the loop using `disable` if you wish, but it's not essential. (What is essential is that you stop incrementing your counter when `c` becomes zero.)