# verilog synthesis not converging after 2000 iterations

Tags: verilog, hardware, xilinx, hdl

I have written the below code for a simple multiplication of 2 n-bit numbers(here n=16). It is getting simulated with desired output waveform but the problem is, it is not getting synthesized in vivado 17.2 even though I have written a **static 'for loop'**(ie., loop iteration is constant). I am getting below mentioned error.

> [Synth 8-3380] loop condition does not converge after 2000 iterations

Note: I have written

```
for(i=i;i<n;i=i+1)
```

instead of

```
for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1)
```

because the latter one was executing once again after i reached n. So that is not a mistake. Kindly someone help. Thank you for your time

```
//unsigned integer multiplier
module multiplication(product,multiplier,multiplicand,clk,rset);
parameter n = 16; 
output reg [(n<<1)-1:0]product;
input [n-1:0]multiplier, multiplicand;
input clk,rset;
reg [n:0]i='d0; 
always @( posedge clk or posedge rset)
begin
    if (rset) product <= 'd0;
    else
    begin
        for(i=i;i<n;i=i+1)
        begin
        product =(multiplier[i] == 1'b1)? product + ( multiplicand << i ): product;
        $display("product =%d,i=%d",product,i);
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not about the iterations of your loop, but about the iterations of the internal algorithm of your synthesis program.  It tells you that Vivado failed to create a circuit that could actually be implemented on your FPGA of choice at your clock speed of choice and which actually does what you're asking for.

Let me elaborate, after I mention two items of general import: don't use blocking assignments (`=`) inside `always @(posedge clk)` blocks.  They almost never do what you want.  Only non-blocking assignments (`<=`) should be clocked.  Secondly, the correct way to synthesize a `for` loop is with `generate`, even though Vivado seems to accept the simple `for`.

You are building a fairly large block of combinatorial logic here.  Remember that when you synthesize combinatorial logic you are asking for a circuit that can evaluate the expression that you've written **within a single clock cycle**.  The actual expression taken into consideration is the one after the for loop has been unrolled.  I.e., you are (conditionally) adding a 16bit number to a 32bit number 16 times, each times shifted one bit further to the left.  Each of these additions has a carry bit.  So each of these additions will actually have to look at all of the upper 16bits of the result of the previous addition, and each will depend on all but the lowest bit of the previous addition.  An adder for one bit + carry needs O(5) gates.  Each addition is conditional, which adds at least one more gate for each bit.  So you are asking for at minimum of 16*16*6 = 1300 interdependent gates that all have to stabilize within a single clock cycle.   Vivado is telling you that it cannot fulfill these requirements.

One way of mitigating this problem will be to synthesize for a lower clock frequency, where the gates have more time to stabilize, and you can thus build longer logic chains.  Another option would be to pipeline the operation, say by only evaluating what corresponds to four iterations of your loop within a single clock cycle and then building the result over several clock cycles.  This will add some bookkeeping logic to your code, but it is inevitable if one wants to evaluate complex expressions with finite resources at high clock frequencies.  It would also introduce you to synchronous logic, which you will have to learn anyway if you want to do anything non-trivial with an FPGA.  Note that this kind of pipelining wouldn't affect throughput significantly, because your FPGA would then be doing several multiplications in parallel.

You may also be able to rewrite the expression to handle the carry bits and interdependencies in a smarter way that allows Vivado to find its way through the expression (there probably is such a way, I assume it synthesizes if you simply write the multiplication operator?).

Finally, many FPGAs come with dedicated multiplier units because multiplication is a common operation, but implementing it in logic gates wastes a lot of resources.  As you found out.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is not a good practice to use **for**, **while** kind of loops if you really want to implement your design on FPGA (Vivado is optimized to be used to implement your design on FPGA). Even if you can successfully synthesize your design, you might face with timing problems or unexpected bugs.

I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370869/loop-convergence-verilog-synthesis).

Edit: I just wanted to inform you that generally controlling timing is very important in HW design, especially when you want to integrate your design with other system, loops can be nightmare for that.

Answer (score 2):

Go back to using your original `for (i=0` loop.

Your error is that you assume i=0 because of `reg [n:0]i='d0;` That is only true the *very first time*. Thus only once, at the start of the simulation.

> because the latter one was executing once again after i reached n.

Yes, the loop will repeat again and again *for every clock cycle*.  That is what `@( posedge clk ...)` does.

More errors:

- You are using blocking assignment in the clock section, use non-blocking:

  product <=(multiplier[i] == 1'b1)? product + ( multiplicand << i ): product;
- Your product is only correct the first time after a reset (when it starts at zero). The second clock cycle after a reset you do the multiplication again but start with the previous value of product.
- Your `i` is a bit big you use 17 bits to count to 16. Also global loop variables have pitfalls. I suggest you use the system Verilog syntax of: `for (int i=0; ....)